# QGIS 2.14.17 repositories "unavailable" can't install plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I can't access the plugin repositories. If I go to plugins -> Manage and install plugins and settings I get unavailable for QGIS official repositories with URL "http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml"

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have a specific reason to use a QGIS version which is this old?

Comment: Upgrade to a supported QGIS version, or try going into the plugin manager and changing http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml to https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml (note https://) if that doesn't help, check if you're behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: Do you have the parameter filled with `?qgis=2.14` ? The URL works well https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.14

Comment: @sn1ks We have education material for this version, that's why we need the plugin repository to work.

Comment: @user2856 Thanks, it actually seems to work when i added an s after http.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the plugin manager and change the url from  `http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml` to `https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml`.

I presume sometime after QGIS 2.14 was released the QGIS team switched the repositories to https.  While `http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml` automatically redirects to https:// (which you can see if you visit http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.14 in your browser), QGIS might not know how to handle this redirection.

Comment: It is not working for me. Even if i do this, after clicking OK, it still reverts to the http link. (I am running an older version of QGIS on a mac since the GRASS plugin works smoothly on this.)

Comment: There's nothing else you can then apart from upgrading or going to the plugin page for your version (e.g. plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.18) and downloading the plgin .zip you want and installing manually