# QGIS Plugin Manager is not available in QGIS 2.18. for Mac

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, mac

I cannot access the repository because it's not available, and when I updated it doesn't work. So, I cannot install plugins.

I already try to download the plugin and saved it in the path */Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins* but I got this error:

```
2021-07-15T22:43:44 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
line 342, in startPlugin
                plugins[packageName].initGui()
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/semiautomaticclassificationplugin.py",
line 1198, in initGui
                htmlText = open(lWelcome, 'r').read()           IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
u'/Users/alejandragutierrezocampo/.qgis2//python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/welcome.html'
```

Comment: I was just wondering: why QGIS 2.18?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change plugin repo URL in Plugin Manager settings from http:// to https:// https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372809/2856